# Compare key and values in json string using scala

Tags: json, scala

Want to compare the first json string with the other 2 json string.
First the keys should match . If they match , then compare the nested key and values.

```
 val of1 = "{\"keyA\":{\"1\":13,\"0\":202}}"
  val of2 = "{\"keyA\":{\"1\":12,\"0\":201}}"
  val of3 = "{\"keyB\":{\"1\":12}}"
```

Should throw Error for key mismatch.

```
 val of1 = "{\"keyA\":{\"1\":13,\"0\":202}}"
  val of2 = "{\"keyA\":{\"1\":12,\"0\":201}}"
  val of2 = "{\"keyA\":{\"1\":11,\"0\":200}}"
```

This should return true, as both keys match and also sub keys 1 and 0 have more values than sub key of json 2 and json 3.The numbers are Long values.

Please help.

Below is my try.

```
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

  val of1 = "{\"keyA\":{\"1\":13,\"0\":202}}"
  val of2 = "{\"keyA\":{\"1\":12,\"0\":201}}"
  val of3 = "{\"keyB\":{\"1\":12}}"


  def OffsetComparator(json1: String, json2: String, json3:String): Boolean = {

    val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
    
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    
    val jsonObj1 = mapper.readValue(json1, classOf[Map[String, Map[String, Long]]])
    val jsonObj2 = mapper.readValue(json2, classOf[Map[String, Map[String, Long]]])
    val jsonObj3 = mapper.readValue(json3, classOf[Map[String, Map[String, Long]]])


//Trying to get the key and compare first
    val mapA = jsonObj1.keySet.foreach(i=>jsonObj1.keySet(i).toString)
    val mapB = jsonObj2.keySet
    val mapC = jsonObj3.keySet



   println( (jsonObj1.keySet == jsonObj3.keySet) )

      if (mapA.keySet != mapB.keySet || mapA.keySet != mapC.keySet) throw new Exception("partitions mismatch")

      mapA.keys.forall(k => (mapA(k).asInstanceOf[Long] > mapB(k).asInstanceOf[Long] && mapA(k).asInstanceOf[Long] > mapC(k).asInstanceOf[Long]))

// getting error :java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long when i am casting as Long.Not su

  }

  println(OffsetComparator(of1, of2,of3))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with https://github.com/gnieh/diffson. ITs available for circe, spray-json and play-json.

Your example with Circe:

```
import diffson._
import diffson.lcs._
import diffson.jsonpatch.lcsdiff._

import io.circe._
import diffson.circe._
import diffson.jsonpatch._
import io.circe.parser._

val decoder = Decoder[JsonPatch[Json]]
val encoder = Encoder[JsonPatch[Json]]

implicit val lcs = new Patience[Json]

val json1 = parse(of1)
val json2 = parse(of2)

val patch =
  for {
    json1 <- json1
    json2 <- json2
  } yield diff(json1, json2)

print(patch)
```

That gives:

```
Right(JsonPatch(List(Replace(Chain(Left(keyA), Left(0)),201,None), Replace(Chain(Left(keyA), Left(1)),12,None))))
```

take a look to see how it works https://index.scala-lang.org/gnieh/diffson/diffson-circe/4.0.3?target=_2.13

For Circe, indlude the dependence:

```
"org.gnieh" %% f"diffson-circe" % "4.0.3"
```

Comment: I already use jackson in other modules. Would like to stick to jackson for any parsing requirements.